# How to extract a string from 2 strings in Excel counting from the second string instead from the default left side

Tags: excel, string, formula

Here's a string:

`Sample text here, EXTRACTTHIS(), and ignore the rest.`

I want `EXTRACTTHIS()` to be extracted, so I used this simple formula:

`=MID(LEFT(A5,FIND("()",A5)+1),FIND(" ",A5)+1,LEN(A5))`

However I got this:
`text here, EXTRACTTHIS()`

Of course I can just mod it to be `=MID(LEFT(A6,FIND("()",A6)+1),FIND(" ",A6)+10,LEN(A6))` to get `EXTRACTTHIS()`.

But I want this formula to work with the whole column such as the following example:

`I give you the next sample: WHAT_IF_THE_STRING_LENGTH_IS_DIFFERENT(), what to do?`

The problem is that Excel counts from the left side of the parent string. I want Excel to count the 1st substring ' ' from the right side of the 2nd substring which is (). Is it doable?

Comment: the `StrReverse()` function looks for a string from the right and returns its position counted from the left.

Comment: Why not simply `=MID(A4,FIND($E$1,A4),LEN($E$1))`? Here E1 is the string to be extracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your examples, it appears you want to extract the substring that ends with `()`.

If that is not what you mean, please be more specific.

Try: `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("()",A1)+1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))`

- Find the location of the `()`: `FIND("()",A1)`
- Extract the portion of the string up to and including the `()`
  `LEFT(A1, ... +1) => Sample text here, EXTRACTTHIS()`
- Then extract the last space separated substring from that
  `TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(... , " ",REPT(" ",99)),99))`

[image]

[image]